# Dataset.map() throws ClassCastException

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, classcastexception

I'm trying to iterate over a dataset using map function, returning the elements without any change to a new variable. And then call the collect method. I get the class cast exception.ClassCastException. what am I missing?

```
def fun() {
   val df = Seq(Person("Max", 33), 
                Person("Adam", 32), 
                Person("Muller", 62)).toDF()

   val encoderPerson = Encoders.product[Person]

   val personDS: Dataset[Person] = df.as[Person](encoderPerson)

   val newPersonDS = personDS.map { iter2 => iter2}

   newPersonDS.collect()
}


case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.query.Person cannot be cast to com.query.Person
    at com.query.MyClass$$anonfun$1.apply(MyClass.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.mapelements_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.deserializetoobject_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.agg_doAggregateWithKeysOutput_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: What kind of Encoders.product, df.as array holds the values? And please update your question with Exception logs.

Comment: In addition, the exception is not consistent, sometimes it throws and sometimes not with the same data

Comment: try  to use show instead of collect and let me know the error if it gives

Comment: show return:  
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 11.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 13, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.query.Person cannot be cast to com.query.Person
 at com.query.myClass$$anonfun$1.apply(myClass.scala:43)

Comment: at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.mapelements_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.deserializetoobject_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)

Comment: at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)

Comment: at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)

Comment: at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
 at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
 at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)

Comment: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)